# How to use @IdToken in Quarkus Apps when application-type=service?

Tags: quarkus, microprofile

I can access @IdToken when running this Quarkus guide: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect-web-authentication. It uses "quarkus.oidc.application-type=web-app".

However when I try to access @IdToken in this other Quarkus guide (https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect), I get the following exception:

```
io.quarkus.oidc.OIDCException: Current identity is not associated with an ID token
```

The only difference that I see is that the second guide uses "quarkus.oidc.application-type=service" which is the default.

I've tried to pass in both an access token and an id token, which I retrieve from Keycloak earlier, in the Authorization header, but without luck.

How can I get @IdToken to work to protect service applications as in the second guide?

To reproduce copy this snippet in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/blob/master/security-openid-connect-quickstart/src/main/java/org/acme/security/openid/connect/UsersResource.java:

```
@Inject
@IdToken
JsonWebToken idToken;

@GET
@RolesAllowed("user")
@Path("/myname")
public String getUserName() {
   return idToken.getName();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Quarkus OIDC `service` applications can only deal with the bearer tokens coming with the HTTP Authorization header.
Quarkus OIDC `web-app` applications are extracting ID and access tokens from the authorization code grant response.
So for the `service` application you can get the name directly from the access token. If the access token is opaque/binary then the user name will be returned with the token instrospection response and can be accessed from `Principal.getName()`(supported starting from Quarkus 1.6.0.CR1)
HTH

Comment: Thanks Sergey! That's what I've done as workaround. I think it's pretty confusing though. I thought JWT tokens contain id tokens and access tokens which can be accessed via the annotations.